# Selecting only direct descendant

Tags: c#, xpath

I have this structure:

```
<root>
  <properties>
    <property name="test">
      <value>X</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <things>
    <thing>
      <properties>
        <property name="test">
          <value>Y</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
    </thing>
  </things>
</root>
```

Is there an XPath expression which will select *only* the test property with value X if run with `<root>` as root, and only the one with value Y if run with `thing` as root?

I thought that `/properties/property[@name='test']` would require it to be a direct child, but that seems to return nothing. If I remove the slash, I get both `property` elements (I'm using C#, with `XElement root = ...; root.XPathSelectElements(xpathexpression);`).

Comment: Your expression is looking for a *properties* element with an attribute of "name" with value "test". That doesn't exist.

Comment: Whoops. Typical thing that happens when trying to avoid using actual data... I'll fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `Property` and not `Properties`. Try `./properties/property[@name='test']`

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that `/properties/property[@name='test']` would require it to
>   be a direct child, but that seems to return nothing.

Any XPath expression that starts with a `/` is an *absolute* XPath expression -- it is evaluated using the document node (/) as the initial context node.

In your case:

/properties/property[@name='test']

tries to select a top element node named `properties` (and then its child) and this correctly selects no nodes, because the top element of the XML document has a different name -- `root`.

**You want**:

```
/root/properties/property[@name='test']
```

**The following *relative* expression is what you want to work in both cases** (with initial context node `/root` and `/root/things/thing`):

```
properties/property[@name='test']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an absolute path when you should be using a relative one, this works to select only the one right under root;

```
        string txt = @"<root><properties><property name=""test""><value>X</value></property></properties><things><thing><properties><property name=""test""><value>Y</value></property></properties></thing></things></root>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(txt);
        var root = doc.Root;
        var val = root.XPathSelectElements("properties/property[@name='test']");
```